# Nested routes in react - Route inside a route - conditionally route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-component

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={NAVIGATION_PATH_FILE_UPLOAD}>
        <FileUpload/>
    </Route>
    <Route exact path={NAVIGATION_PATH_PRICE_VALIDATION}>
        {grantViewPermissionsToScreens(user, SCREEN_PRICE_VALIDATION) ? <PriceValidation/> : <PZRHome/>}
    </Route>
    <Route exact path={NAVIGATION_PATH_PRICEZONE_REASSIGNMENT}>
        <PZRHome/>
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

In the above piece of code depending on the user i have given access to either pricevalidation or PZRHome component (2nd route). instead of loading the  component , in its place i want to route to that component.(replace PZRHome component within 2nd route , with the route to PZRHome (3rd route)). how can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Below approach might work:

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={NAVIGATION_PATH_FILE_UPLOAD}>
        <FileUpload />
      </Route>
    {
      grantViewPermissionsToScreens(user, SCREEN_PRICE_VALIDATION) &&
        <Route exact path={NAVIGATION_PATH_PRICE_VALIDATION}>
          <PriceValidation />
        </Route>
    }
    {
      !grantViewPermissionsToScreens(user, SCREEN_PRICE_VALIDATION) &&
        <Route exact path={NAVIGATION_PATH_PRICEZONE_REASSIGNMENT}>
          <PZRHome />
        </Route>
    }
      <Route exact path={NAVIGATION_PATH_PRICEZONE_REASSIGNMENT}>
        <PZRHome />
      </Route>
</Switch>
```